# NSSplitView screen artefacts

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssplitview

I'm buildng an app for macOS with an NSSplitView. In the top frame of the splitview, there is another NSSplitView, this time vertical, to make a three-pane window. (Two frames across the top, one frame across the bottom, a bit like FCP etc.)

It looks like this at launch:
[image: App at launch]

However if I resize the app window, or move any of the dividers, then the original divider positions stay drawn on screen.
Like this:
[image: After resizing]

How can I remove these screen artefacts?

Comment: Is this XIB or Storyboarded? My UI glitches got away when I switched to storyboard.s

Comment: Hi Marek_H,  this project is XIB, but not using story board.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED.
I simply sub-classed NSSPlitView, and set the class-type in the inspector to my new sub-class. This got rid of the screen artefacts. I have no idea why this works.